# How can I access my home laptop's linux prompt through my router?

Tags: linux, networking, router

I have a router that is reachable from public internet and the IP address what I'm receiving from my ISP is the address on the internet. So I can easily do port forwards.

I have a laptop with Fedora Linux. And I would like to connect it to the router and access it from the internet or from another laptop:

Is it possible somehow?

If I type

```
ssh admin@my_name.asuscomm.com
```

or

```
ssh admin@192.168.1.1 (from LAN)
```

I can login into the router.

But how could I login to that Fedora Linux? Something like this is possible?

```
ssh admin@my_name.asucomm.com:<some_port_number>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set up Port Forwarding on your Router.

The port forwarding rule usually goes something like:
If I (Router) receive connectivity on a particular port (say 21567) using TCP (or UDP), forward any traffic coming onto that port, to an IP_address:port within your internal network.

So assuming your Linux Device within your network has the IP address of 192.168.1.100, and your SSH daemon on the Linux device runs on port 22, you need to set up a Port Forwarding Rule on the router to point to 192.168.1.100:22.

For now, lets assume you are using my example (port 21567), and you have a public IP of 123.123.123.235 then from outside your network connection, you SSH to --> 123.123.123.235:21567

Hope this make sense.

Comment: @user3719454 Consider installing something like fail2ban on your Linux machine to block all the login attempts you may get.

Comment: Agree with that comment, not so much may get... But **WILL** get if you leave port 22 open to the wild.

Comment: I managed to login to my linux :) But it worked only if I enabled DMZ (even if according to https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ the port was opened). I also had to start sshd

Answer (score 1):

Not to repeat the other answers, here are a few other tips.

Most routers allow for Dynamic DNS to be setup where they will broadcast your current IP to a DNS service and allow you to associate a DNS host with your external IP.  This makes it easy to `ssh me@myhost.dynamicdns.com`.   There are several providers out there and I'm not advocating one over the other.  You'll need to do your own research but searching for dynamic DNS will get you started. This way you don't have to keep track of changing public IPs.

Second, you have a couple of choices for getting to the Fedora system.  Port forwarding is one way and this entails (as outline in other answers) setting up a specific incoming port and the internal host for the router to send the request to.

An alternative of that option is to use a feature called DMZ on most routers which basically forwards all packets to you IP to a specific host; in this case your Fedora system.  Of course there are significant security risks using any approach and you need to ensure that YOU have setup your Fedora system with the forrect firewall and other security measures.  The firewall / router won't protect you once the traffic passes through.

I prefer the DMZ approach and simply enable only port 22 access.  Where i need to add 443 or another port its a simple config on the server itself and not a reconfiguration of the router which can disrupt traffic while the changes are applied.

Comment: If this answered your question feel free to mark it so, good luck.